# Why would this MySQL index be getting used for this query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following query, without the explain) is executing quite slowly (multiple seconds) despite being a very basic lookup of the last 5 ids on a MySQL table.  I noticed in the explain, it's using a key that makes no sense as we aren't using that field ("complimentary") in the query.

If we remove the COALESCE, it acts normally.  Unfortunately, that's not an option for us right now as we need NULL values (on other fields) to be forced to an empty string or some other value in the output.

Unfortunately, this query is being used in a system where we cannot alter the query.

As-is, why does the execution path happen the way it does?

```
mysql> explain SELECT COALESCE(bags.id,'') AS "_g1",
    -> bags.id AS "bags_id"
    -> FROM bags
    -> GROUP BY 1
    -> ORDER BY concierge_bags.id DESC
    -> LIMIT 5 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: bags
         type: index 
possible_keys: NULL
          key: index_bags_on_complimentary
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 286582
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE bags \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bags
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `complimentary` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_bags_on_complimentary` (`complimentary`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=284632 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note that I have trimmed out some extra fields on bags that are not in this query.

Comment: Is `bags.id` really nullable? I would expect that `id` is a customary name for the primary key of the table. Primary keys cannot be nullable. Can you please edit your question and post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE bags` so we can see the exact definition of the table with its indexes?

Comment: bags.id is not really nullable but the state field unfortunately is.  In addition, this query is generated by a blackbox system, so we don't really have much control over it.  Just trying to understand why the query executes as it does.  I have updated the question with the table create statement.

Comment: How is `state` nullable? It says `NOT NULL` in the column definition. And what does `state` have to do with the query at all? I am starting to suspect that you're simply looking at the EXPLAIN for some different query. Also I notice your CREATE TABLE output is not valid, there's a comma after the index on complimentary. So you have apparently edited this before posting. Makes me wonder what else you are editing.

Comment: Also your SELECT statement references `concierge_bags.id` but that references a table (or table alias) not defined in the query. You need to post the *real* query in the question if you ask people to help you analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use CASE instead of COALESCE? Why do you group on 1?

Comment: This query is being used in a system where we cannot alter the query.  Do you understand why, as-is, the execution path happens the way it does?